# Using zymichost to create a table

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to use zymichost to create a table for a user, I have the following:

```
`db`.`USERS`(
`username`VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`password`CHAR(22) NOT NULL,
`jobCategory`VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( username )
);
```

and I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`origincareer_zymichost_db`.`JOBSEEKERS`( `username`VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL AUTO' at line 1

Not sure what to do.

Comment: You're missing the `create table` part before your statement. And your error message does not fit the code you're providing.

Comment: Thank you so much, new to databases, however it now says "Incorrect column specifier for column 'username'". should username be uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `create table` and remove `auto_increment` (you can't increment a username, only numbers)

```
create table db.`USERS`
(
  `username`     VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `password`     CHAR(22)    NOT NULL,
  `jobCategory`  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be89a/1)

And always store only the hash of passwords and not the passwords itself!